# Excel VBA UDF Recalculation Indicator Parameter

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF function within a xlam workbook that connects to a database and executes a query, based on the parameters entered. This function is going to be used hundreds of times within different workbooks. Since it is going to be used in a series of different workbooks, that is the reason why I used a xam workbook.

The issue is that using the UDF function so many times, slows the Recalculation down to much since it is recalculating when it doesn't need to. I was thinking about adding another indicator parameter in the UDF that if set to zero, it will just return the value of the cell before the Recalculation started. Is there anyway to do this? I was thinking about adding a conditional statement that would use something like application.caller.value to get the value.

Comment: Does the UDF always perform the same query on the same data? Or is the query result likely to change frequently? One possibility is to make a somewhat more general query and hold the results in the xlam workbook (on it's own hidden worksheet) and then perform subsequent lookups on that data -- if that's possible given your situation.

Comment: No the data can reference one of multiple databases or tables. Also the criteria of the query that is specified through a number of parameters can be different. The idea for the udf, is to use that instead of dumping in a series of large result files produced by a a software into Excel. Then only using a very small subset of the data. Given how how general the UDF is, having the data in hidden tabs on the xlam workbook would be hard. Therefore I am hoping that I can somehow determine the value of the cell before the Recalculation.

Comment: Also with multiple users using the workbook and checking the results, storing the results on the xlam won't work I think. This is because the xlam is stored on each users computer not on a shared network.

Comment: What is the code and do you use `Application.Volatile` at all?